# The methods for Drag and Drop in NSOutlineView are not getting called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsoutlineview

I'm trying to enable drag and drop functionality for NSOutlineView in my MacOS app. I want to drag a child from a folder to another folder within the outline view.

[I want test asset 1 to be dragged and dropped in Group 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8bu3.png)

I have myOutlineView and a controller which is a data source and a delegate of my outline view.

In my outline view controller I have these three methods:

```
-(BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView writeItems:(NSArray *)items toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pboard

-(NSDragOperation)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView validateDrop:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)info proposedItem:(id)item proposedChildIndex:(NSInteger)index

-(BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView acceptDrop:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)info item:(id)item childIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

None of them is being called. My nib is setup properly, my outline view is getting filled and all of the functionality is working except the drag and drop feature.

I have also registered the drag type in awake from nib:

```
[_paraOutlineView registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"QStyleSheetModel"]];
```

I also wrote this:

```
[_paraOutlineView setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSDragOperationMove forLocal:YES];
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Do you call [`setDraggingSourceOperationMask:forLocal:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1527199-setdraggingsourceoperationmask?language=objc)?

Comment: @Willeke yes I did. But it still does not work.

Comment: Implementing and calling the mentioned methods should do it. Any overrides or custom views in the cells?

Comment: Yes, I have a custom view that derives from NSOutlineView. But none of the functions in the custom view gets called due to dragging and there are no overrides of these functions.

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully resolved the issue! Although I couldn't initially pinpoint the exact problem, it turned out that the overridden function "setDataSource" in my code was making a call to an "init" function, which belonged to a different interface. This unexpected call to the "init" function was preventing the execution of "writeItems:toPasteBoard." The solution was to remove the call to the "init" function, and now everything works as expected.